# How to send different Events to different Google Analytics accounts from a Same Page?

Tags: google-analytics

Scenario :
I have created a Web UI, where users can login and validate their ~REPORTS~ by uploading and the reports will be validated in the back-end and the results will be displayed. The reports are not all the same and sometimes it will contain columns/values which were never seen before.

My Manager's ask is to display only the following, not to display any other details in Google Analytics Events.

1. How many users Logged into the UI
2. How many reports were uploaded for Validation ?
3. How many reports passed the validation ?
4. How many reports failed the validation ?

However i need certain more details,

1. If any New Columns shows up, how many times they are shown up ?
2. If any Validations failed a Check List, which check List failure is often showing up, so that i can go ahead and fix the source of the report itself or validation code.

Similarly i have some more metrics.

So my Need is,

```
 Two Google Analytics Events collecting different events from the Same
 Page.
```

How can i do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to achieve separation of events.

First, you could use the hierarchical organization of events to separate the events your manager cares about (into one or a few Event Categories) from the other events you also want to track (into their own Event Category).

If they really cannot show up together in GA at all, you can set up two different Properties in the same Account, or two different Accounts (although that seems like more trouble than should be needed, to me), and send some events to one and some events to the other.

I'm not sure whether you can do it without Google Tag Manager, so this answer may not be helpful if you're using GA directly.

If you have GTM, you can create multiple Settings Variables, one with the main GA Property ID and one with the Property ID where you want to send your additional events. GTM does not care about Accounts, so whether the Properties are in the same or different Accounts will not matter.

When defining your events, choose the appropriate settings variable to send the data to the correct GA Property. We do this with our GTM - sending JavaScript Error events to a separate property so they will not create a lot of noise in the main one.

Comment: I'm using GYM only, can you share a sample code snippe configuring two GA accounts and event triggers to two GA accounts

Comment: I've never implemented GA directly, but it looks like you can add a second GA property ID and a name to distinguish it from the first one:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers
Then, when you want to send events to the second GA location, you prefix "send" with the name you chose: `ga('send', ...)` versus `ga('zeus.send', ...)`